# AutoComplete Suggestions in a Textbox by use of "Static Page Method"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

While implementing Static Page Method, clicking on the Add AutoComplete page method smart tag option, is not allowing to create a new page method named **GetCompletionList**: which represent what the user has typed into the TextBox (prefixText) and the number of auto-complete suggestions to show (count).

> [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(),
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]   public static
>   string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string
>   contextKey) {   return default(string[]);   }

Error message appears as **"Cannot Create Page Method since no code behind is found"**

The Error only arises when we do this auto-complete implementation in an already existing application, instead if we implement in an entirely new application then the problem does not arise.

What could be the solution to this problem ?
Any help would be greatly appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are doing this on an aspx page that doesn't have a CS file associated with it. 
Put this code in the cs file associated with this page.

If there is none, create one and add it in the page, like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyLib.MyPage" %>
```